# CSS boxing long not-wrapped texts with scroll and not autoexpands

Tags: html, css, overflow

I've been trying to solve a problem using tables created using <div></div> and I have an ugly problem when things inside a cell go beyond a small size.
Here I leave an example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            div.table {
                display: table;
                width: 500px;
            }
            div.table div.row {
                display: table-row;
            }
            div.table div.row div {
                display: table-cell;
                border: 2px solid red;
            }
            #BOX {
                border: 5px solid green;
                overflow-x: scroll;
                overflow-y: hidden;
                width: 300px;
            }
            #TEXT {
                white-space: nowrap;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="table"><div class="row">
            <div>HELLO WORLD</div>
            <div id="BOX">
                <span id="TEXT">
                    aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa
                </span>
            </div>
            <div>HELLO WORLD</div>
        </div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**What I need:**

When the text of "TEXT" is short it look something like this:
[well formatted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuUiq.png)

**What I don't want**:

When the text of "TEXT" is long, central <div> expands until it can hold it all and the table also becomes as wide as needed. Something like this:
[not what I wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XhWu.png)

**Question**:

Does anyone know how can I make it work?

Note: I need it to scroll horizontally only and the width of "BOX" can't be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/3YEeH/

```
#TEXT {
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-width: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this? It should force that cell to stay a certain width.

```
#TEXT { width: 150px;}
```

Or maybe even...

```
#TEXT { max-width: 150px;}
```

Comment: I've tried to set width to 150px to #TEXT, then #BOX, and also to both at the same time, but I still have the same behavior.
thanx anyway